# SQL Query Visualisation Tool suggestion

Tags: sql

I am looking for a tool that gets my SQL query as input and creates a flow diagram.
I need this tool to be database agnostic, meaning, it should be able to create the flow for any query. 
Any help is appreciated

Comment: What do you mean by "the flow"? Also, SQL isn't database agnostic, different DB engines have sligthy different syntaxes.

Comment: Are you looking for a visualization of the query, its execution, or its results?

Answer (score 0):

One possible way is to use [SQL Developer](https://www.oracle.com/database/sqldeveloper/technologies/download/) and make it do the [execution plan](https://www.databasestar.com/sql-developer-execution-plan/). SQL Developer can work with Oracle, MySQL, Microsoft SQL Server, Microsoft Access, Sybase, Teradata and IBM DB2 RDBMS. But for most of them you may not be able to run the execution plan.